# Setting content of dijit.layout.ContentPane declaratively

Tags: dojo

The following dijit created declaratively shows up in Firefox but not other browsers. Am I setting its content incorrectly?

```
<div id="main" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="href:'dashboard.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was trying to load the href content locally from the filesystem instead of over http. An ajax error occurs, I fixed the problem by using a real web server